# Test failures on dependent maven projects

Tags: java, testing, maven, build, dependencies

I have a multiple projects where project X is dependent on project Y.
The tests on project X uses project Y which reads a config file. ( X --> Y --> configfile)
I am excluding some configuration files from the JARs using the maven-jar-plugin.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
    <inherited>true</inherited>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
                    <exclude>*.xml</exclude>
                    <exclude>*.*conf*</exclude>
                    <exclude>*.*prop*</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When running "Maven test" on my project everything works well and all test are successful.
But when running "Maven package" project X is failing its tests because project Y cannot find the config file.

My best guess is that when running the "package" goal, project X runs against the already built JAR of project Y instead of its .class files. Am I correct? What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: How about creating another config file for the project X? any constraint preventing to do this?

Comment: I have many config files in each project which are only relevant for that project scope. I don't want to make a mess by copying a lot of config files to multiple projects

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could be interested by the section **How to create a jar containing test classes** of [the maven-jar-plugin page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/usage.html).

The idea is to create two different jars for your project Y: one test-jar besides your current packaged jar. You have two executions of the maven-jar-plugin, one for your current jar and one for the test-jar, for which configuration files are not filtered.

To allow the project X to refer to the test-jar of project Y, you would also need to add a dependency to this jar in test *scope*.

Note that the page advises another approach which consist in creating another Maven project dedicated for your test classes for which you will not exclude any configuration files.